# Using WebRTC with Socket.io

Tags: socket.io, webrtc

I'm trying to create an app for making audio calls in the browser. I found this tutorial and started using it as a basis: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/WebRTC-PeerConnection.html

After some tweaking to fit my needs. I ended up with the following:

```
var iceServers = [
    { url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
    { url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca', credential: 'muazkh', username: 'webrtc@live.com' }
];

var sdpConstraints = {
    optional: [],
    mandatory: {
        OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
        OfferToReceiveVideo: false
    }
};

var DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement = {
   DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement: true
};

var optional = {
   optional: [DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement]
};


var peer = new webkitRTCPeerConnection({
    'iceServers': iceServers,
    optional
});


function getAudio(successCallback, errorCallback){

    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(
      {
        audio: true, 
        video: false
      },
      successCallback,
      errorCallback
    );

}


function send_SDP() {
    console.log('now emitting send sdp message');
    SocketService.emit('message', {
        'conversation_id': me.conversation_id,
        'targetUser': to,
        'sdp': peer.localDescription
    });
}


function startCall(){

    getAudio(
        function(stream){

            console.log('peer');
            console.log(peer);

            console.log('adding local stream');
            peer.addStream(stream);

            peer.createOffer(function(offerSDP) {
                console.log('now creating offer');
                peer.setLocalDescription(offerSDP, function(){
                    console.log('local description is set. now informing peer');

                    SocketService.emit('message', {
                        'conversation_id': me.conversation_id,
                        'targetUser': to,
                        'offerSDP': offerSDP
                    });
                },
                function(){
                    console.log('error setting local description')
                });
                console.log('now emitting offerSDP message');
            }, 
            function(){
                console.log('error occured while creating offer');
            }, 
            sdpConstraints
            );


            console.log('now calling ' + to);

        },
        function(err){
            console.log('an error occured while getting the audio');
        }
    );


};


function createAnswer(offerSDP) {

    getAudio(
        function(stream){
            console.log('now creating answer');
            console.log(stream);

            console.log('NOW ADDING STREAM');
            peer.addStream(stream);

            var remoteDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(offerSDP);
            peer.setRemoteDescription(remoteDescription);

            peer.createAnswer(function(answerSDP) {
                peer.setLocalDescription(answerSDP, function(){
                    console.log('done setting local description');
                    console.log('now emitting answer sdp message');
                    SocketService.emit('message', {
                        'conversation_id': me.conversation_id,
                        'targetUser': to,
                        'answerSDP': answerSDP
                    });
                },
                function(){
                    console.log('error setting local description');
                });
            }, function(err){
                alert('error occured while creating answer');
                console.log(err);
            }, sdpConstraints);

        },
        function(err){
            alert('error occured while getting the audio for answer');
        }
    );

};


SocketService.on('message', function(msg){

    if(msg.offerSDP){

        var remoteDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(msg.offerSDP);
        peer.setRemoteDescription(remoteDescription, function(){
            console.log('done setting remote description');
            createAnswer(msg.offerSDP);
        },
        function(){
            console.log('error setting remote description');
        });

    }

    if(msg.answerSDP) {
        var remoteDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(msg.answerSDP);
        peer.setRemoteDescription(remoteDescription, function(){
            console.log('finished signaling offers and answers!');
        },
        function(){
            console.log('error signaling offers and answers');
        });
    }


    if(msg.candidate) {

        var candidate = msg.candidate.candidate;
        var sdpMLineIndex = msg.candidate.sdpMLineIndex;

        peer.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate({
            sdpMLineIndex: sdpMLineIndex,
            candidate: candidate
        }));
    }


});


peer.onaddstream = function(stream){
    console.log('now adding remote stream');
    console.log(stream);
    audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream); //this is where the error occurs
};      


peer.onicecandidate = function(event) {
    console.log('on ice candidate');
    var candidate = event.candidate;
    console.log(candidate);
    console.log('after ice candidate');
    if(candidate) {
        console.log('now emitting candidate message');
        SocketService.emit('message', {
            'conversation_id': me.conversation_id,
            'targetUser': to,
            'candidate': candidate
        });
    }

    console.log(typeof candidate);
    if(typeof candidate == 'undefined') {
        console.log('now sending sdp');
        send_SDP();
    }

};


peer.ongatheringchange =  function(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget && e.currentTarget.iceGatheringState === 'complete') {
        send_SDP();
    }
};
```

What happens here is that, first the `startCall` method is called when the call button is clicked. This triggers the browser to request access to the webcam and mic. Once the user accepts it, the `addStream` method is used to add local stream. After that, an offer is created and local description is set. Then I use socket.io to send message to the peer for sending an offer. Once the offer is received, the remote rtc session description is set using the offerSDP sent via socket.io. Once that's done, the answer is initiated. This will trigger the browser to request for the webcam and mic. At this point, the error occurs in the peer who receives the call. Then the stream is added to the peer. A session description is then set and the peer creates an answer. Once that's done, the local description is set and a message containing the answer is sent to the calling peer. The session description is then set and that finalizes the signaling part. At this point, the error occurs on the calling peer.

But I'm getting the following error whenever I get to the part where it adds the remote stream from the other peer.

`Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `stream` that you're passing to `createObjectUrl`? Are you sure it's a stream?

Comment: You have ran tests on which browser?

Comment: @ObscureGeek I'm mainly using Chrome and Chromium in Ubuntu.
@xdumaine yes it's a stream. I used `console.log` to check

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu Since you are only testing on Chrome and Chromium you tried using `webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);`?

Comment: yes, it says its already deprecated. I think it falls back to using `URL.createObjectURL` if I use that. And then I get the same error

Comment: @Kyokasuigetsu I'm like 99% sure you're wrong.  `stream` is actually an event object which has a `stream` property. See my answer, and give that a shot and let me know if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`peer.onaddstream` is not fired with a stream, it's fired with an event object that contains the stream:

Change this:

```
peer.onaddstream = function(stream){
    console.log('now adding remote stream');
    console.log(stream);
    audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
};
```

To this:

```
peer.onaddstream = function(event){
    console.log('now adding remote stream');
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.stream);
    audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
};
```